# menu not showing on mobile view

Tags: menus

I am using the latest version of wordpress with the festy.beautheme theme. The drop down menu doesnt show on mobile - or when the browser window is very small. Its the drop down menu that is three lines. When you click it, it should have a drop down menu.

It works fine on a full desktop screen - but when I shrink the screen (or view it on mobile), the three lines menu does create a drop down. Nothing happens when you click it. Here is the link. Anyone have any ideas?
http://bigplatinum.mydevportals.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your themes style.css there is a media query written on line no. 12401

```
@media (max-width: 991px)
.header__wrapper .main-menu3 {
     display: none;  
}
```

first, comment on this line now you can see your menu shown in your mobile view also.
To toggle this when clicking on three lines you have to add a little jquery code:

```
$('.button-show').click(function(){
    $('.main-menu3').toggle();
});
```

or you can achieve the same thing in one more way:

```
$('.button-show').click(function(){
    $('.main-menu3').toggleClass('hide_menu');
});
```

Now in your theme CSS write follwing css:

```
.hide_menu{
    display:none;
}
```

let me know if you are having any more doubts.
Thank you
Regards,
Ravi Thakkar